# ExternalInterface.addCallback is not working

Tags: javascript, actionscript

This is my AC3 code

```
private function uploadet( dosya:String ):void {

        var uploader:URLRequest = new URLRequest(dosya);
            localFile.upload(uploader);
    }


        var a = flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("uploadet",uploadet);
```

And this is Javascript

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");



        function uploadet(dosya){
        var myFlashMovie = swfobject.getObjectById("myId");
       myFlashMovie.uploadet(dosya);
        }

        </script>        


<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
-->
</style></head>
    <body >
        <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="120">
                <param name="movie" value="SimpleUploader.swf" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="SimpleUploader.swf" width="300" height="120">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <div>

                </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
          <div id="flash"  align="center">

          </div>

        <div align="center"><b>Javascript Feedback:</b></div>
        <div align="center" id="output"></div>        

        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadet('dsadsa.php');" />
```

I cant get it work, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you must deploy the flash app on a webserver in order to test it (or make yourself a local web server). 
flash player won't allow you to use external interface if you load the file from local host as a file (file:///c:.....).

Comment: Indeed, that solved the problem in my case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use getObjectById method to get the swf object.
You can use the following code:

```
swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", callbackFn);
function callbackFn(status) {
  if (status.success) {
     var obj = status.ref;
     document.getElementById("but1").onclick = function() {
       if (obj && typeof obj.uploadet!= "undefined") {
         obj.uploadet(dosya);
        }
      };
 }
```

More details you can refer to [Static Embed method:Browser communication test page with callback](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_com2.html)

and [Dynamic Embed method:Browser communication test page with callback](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_dynamic_com2.html)

Comment: This may not have solved his problem but it solved mine.  I believe it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the ExternalInterface without allowing scripting when you embed the SWF, read this [Adobe Knowledge Base](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html) document for more information. In other words, use this HTML if you're embedding it directly on the page:

```
<object ... >
    .
    .
    .
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
</object>
```

Or the following if you're using SWFObject:

```
var parametersObj = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
swfobject.embedSWF(
    swfPath,
    targetElement,
    swfWidth,
    swfHeight,
    minFlashVersion,
    expressInstall,
    flashvarsObj,
    parametersObj,
    attributesObj
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are probably not reaching the right `<OBJECT>` element using:

```
var myFlashMovie = document.getElementById('simpleUploader');
```

Your nested  tags have the same id attribute, producing unexpected results.

You should use SWFObject (a widely known and used flash embedding library) to embed your flash movie and use the method `swfobject.getObjectById()` to properly access your `<OBJECT>` tags.

To learn more about SWFObject, follow this link:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

This is a beginners tutorial available from Adobe (for SWFObject):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

Look for `getObjectById()` in the API documentation by following this link:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api

Comment: yes, i made SWFObject and edited my question, but it is still not working.

Comment: Mind providing some error message? what's happening when it's not working?